# Spilling works in Excel Online but not Excel for Windows

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I have the following function that returns an array of rows:

```
/**
 * Returns the names of people
 * @customfunction mynames
 * @param invocation Custom function handler
 */
function mynames(invocation: CustomFunctions.StreamingInvocation<string[][]>): void{
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    var row1 = ["larry", "moe", "curly"];
    var row2 = ["scoopy", "velma", "shaggy"];
    var rows = [row1, row2];

    invocation.setResult(rows);
  }, 5*1000); // every 5 seconds

  invocation.onCanceled = () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
}
```

Works perfect on Excel online and I get:

```
larry   moe curly
scoopy  velma   shaggy
```

However, Excel for Windows only gives me `larry`. Spilling doesn't seem to be respected in Excel for Windows.

In fact, the examples they explicitly [give in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-dynamic-arrays) have the same behaviour and are also broken on the Windows version of Excel. I iamgine they're also broken on the Mac version as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a build of Excel that supports Dynamic Arrays. Otherwise you can manually array enter (ctrl+shift+enter the formula into the desired cells you want to spill into).

This is currently available in the monthly / “current” channel for windows, and will become available in the semi-annual update that should be rolling out this coming month.

A recent Mac build as of January 2020 should also spill.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So, my add-in got rejected because of this. You're saying the reviewer failed to `ctrl+shift+enter`?

Comment: Hey there, sorry for delay. I think you may need to use an updated requirement set. Based on my understanding of requirement sets, I would suggest using the Excel 1.11 requirement set in the manifest. That will ensure your addin uses the spill behavior on builds that support it.